# Bootstrap Popover & JQuery does not 'show' after 'hide'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have am having an issue with a popover that does not show again after a click event.

I am using AngularJS to watch some dynamic content and I want to reload the popover when that content changes. In the popover is a button linked to function that changes my content. When the button is clicked I want to reload the popover. The 'hide' function works, but then it flickers and does not 'show' the popover until I click the input again. When I do click it, the content is updated. But I want it to 'show' without the user clicking it..

My code is as follow;

The input field;

```
<input id='test' ng-model="form.location" type="text" class="form-control">
```

The popover content

```
<div id="geo" class="popover-body hidden" ng-controller="geoCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="updateGeo">
        <button ng-show="update[0]" id="findme" style="margin: -10px" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="getGeo()"><span class="purp"><i class="fa fa-street-view"></i> FIND ME!</span></button>
        <button ng-hide="update[0]" id="findme" style="margin: -10px" class="btn btn-simple btn-sm" ng-click="getGeo()"><span class="purp"><i class="fa fa-street-view"></i> FIND ME!</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ng-hide/ng-show control what button to show.

The Jquery;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var content = $('[id*="geo"]');

$(document).on('click', '#test', function() {

    $('#test').popover('show')

})

$('#test').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'manual',
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'top',
    content: function () {
        return content.html();
    },
});

$(document).on('click', '#findme', function()
{
    angular.element('#geo').scope().getGeo();
    angular.element('#geo').scope().$apply();

    $('#test').popover('hide');
    $('#test').popover('show')

});
```

Everything works, you click input it displays the popover with the correct button. You click the button, the popover hides, but it does not display again until you re-click input. When it does show the correct content is showing.

How can I get it to show on its own without having to click input a second time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but what if you try to put the 
    $('#test').popover('show');
after the popover hide in a setTimeout(function(){ like this

```
$('#test').popover('hide');
setTimeout(function(){
$('#test').popover('show');
},100);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try!